# Optional Parameter with now (Date) default value

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to assign the default Date Time ( Now ) value for optional parameter.

When assigning the now object to optional parameter below error is raised

```
Constant expression is required
```

Code:

```
Public Sub ReminderMail(Optional ByVal ReminderMailDate As DateTime = Now)

// Code Block

End Sub
```

Comment: What part of the error are you not understanding? Optional parameters have to be constant values. Last time I checked, `Now` changes fairly often.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Initially i can't understand the error, Now got it well -- "Optional parameters have to be constant values"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this :

```
Public Sub ReminderMail(Optional ByVal ReminderMailDate As DateTime = Nothing)

If ReminderMailDate = Nothing Then ReminderMailDate = Now

// Code Block

End Sub
```

Comment: @MattWilko - it's not that different from setting it to `default(DateTime)` in c#.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using an optional parameter, you might want to consider offering two overloads of your `Sub`:

```
Public Sub ReminderMail()
    ReminderMail(DateTime.Now)
End Sub

Public Sub ReminderMail(ByVal ReminderMailDate As DateTime)

// Code Block

End Sub
```

Which from a caller's perspective, operates quite similarly.

Comment: +1. Yes, million times, for maintainability concerns. I was going to post this as an answer myself immediately after I read the accepted answer.